# Detect Pacific timezone with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, time

I want to do a if statment if the current time in pacific time is 11am. how can i do that? here is what i have right now:

```
var time = new Date().getHours();

if(time == 11) {
  alert("this works");
}
```

but that only detects the user's time. how can i do pacific time only?

Comment: Perhaps this might help http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination of `getTimezoneOffset()` and PST (-7), currently Pacific Daylight Time!

```js
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var localHour = new Date().getHours();
var PSTHour = localHour + offset - 7;
PSTHour = PSTHour > 0 ? PSTHour : PSTHour + 24;
console.log('PST hour: ' + PSTHour);
```